# Installing Windows 7 Without Formatting Another Disk Partition?

Tags: windows-7, installation, partitioning

My computer has two hard disk partitions, that is C: and D:, C: partition is about 30 GB and D: partition is about 50GB. In D: There are lot of my important data and I can't lose them, so I cannot format it.

Currently, I have Ubuntu 10.04 on C: partition. I would like to replace it with Windows 7 Ultimate. But I have a doubt about partitioning disk during the installation. Can I install Windows 7 Ultimate without formatting D: ?

Comment: You mean that important data is not backed up?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to format C: to install Windows7, there is no need to format D:.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is very well possible.
When you insert the Win7 installation disc and when you see the the box where you format and select the partition, just format C:\ drive.
Note that softwares installed in D:\ may not work